# How to install keras in RStudio?

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I am using R version 3.5.0 with R studio.

I want to install keras and use the following:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)

devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
install.packages("keras")

library(keras)
install_keras()
```

After  "install_keras()" I get the following error:

```
Creating r-tensorflow conda environment for TensorFlow installation...
Usage: conda [options] [INPUTFILE]
       (STDIN is assumed if no INPUTFILE is given)

conda: error: no such option: --yes
Error: Error 2 occurred creating conda environment r-tensorflow
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

PS.  I just want everything to run on the cpu for now as I don't have a suitable gpu.

Comment: What's the version of your `conda`? [This post](https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/318) suggested that updating `Anaconda` might fix the error

Comment: Thank you.  I think what the problem was that I could not access the newly created r-tensorflow environment.

Comment: I looked in Anconda3> envs folder and there was a "r-tensorflow" folder as well as other evironments that I had created ages ago.  I couldn't make RStudio use the "R-tensorflow" environment and ended up uninstalling Anaconda3 then reinstalling it again which gave an empty envs folder. I ran the code above in Rstudio again and it worked!  There is now just one environment ("r-tensorflow").  I will leave this question open as it isn't an ideal solution as I lost all my old environments. Thanks Tung.

Comment: @Mel I know it's not ideal, but I just had the same problem and your solution worked for me. Thanks for sharing it.